# FBX export problem

Tags: export

I'm trying to export an project in FBX but i got error all the time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init.py", line 636, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv_t_lvidx)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 504, in elem_data_single_int32_array
    return _elem_data_single(elem, name, value, "add_int32_array")
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 451, in _elem_data_single
    getattr(sub_elem, func_name)(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 161, in add_int32_array
    data = array.array(data_types.ARRAY_INT32, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv_t_lvidx)))
  KeyError: ((nan, nan), 523)

  location: <unknown location>:-1
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your Blend file

Comment: It would be very helpful if the error message was [added to your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/196311/edit) as plain text. As an aside, text in images is not searchable and is therefore not as useful for other users as having all text in the body of your question. You may add your blend file using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue with my UV's being out of whack. So I just did a cube projection and then I was allowed to export to fbx.